# TOP function in apache pig

Tags: hive, apache-pig

In a dataset (approx. 200k records), there is column named tags (  comma separated list of tags associated with question. examples of tags are "html","error" etc so on .

php,error,gd,image-processing

php,error,gd,image-processing

lisp,scheme,subjective,clojure

lisp,scheme,subjective,clojure

lisp,scheme,subjective,clojure

lisp,scheme,subjective,clojure

lisp,scheme,subjective,clojure

lisp,scheme,subjective,clojure

lisp,scheme,subjective,clojure

lisp,scheme,subjective,clojure

lisp,scheme,subjective,clojure

lisp,scheme,subjective,clojure

lisp,scheme,subjective,clojure

lisp,scheme,subjective,clojure

lisp,scheme,subjective,clojure

lisp,scheme,subjective,clojure

lisp,scheme,subjective,clojure

lisp,scheme,subjective,clojure

cocoa-touch,objective-c,design-patterns

cocoa-touch,objective-c,design-patterns

cocoa-touch,objective-c,design-patterns

core-animation

django,django-models

django,django-models

aspÃ»net

scala,pattern-matching,oop,object-oriented-design,design-principles

scala,pattern-matching,oop,object-oriented-design,design-principles

scala,pattern-matching,oop,object-oriented-design,design-principles

.
.
.
.
.

how to find top 10 most commonly used tags in dataset? in pig or hive

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

1) tokenize the data
https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.14.0/func.html#tokenize

2) flatten out the bag created by the tokenizer
https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.14.0/basic.html#flatten

3) group by the terms, and count, sg like this:

```
counts = FOREACH (GROUP data BY term) GENERATE
    group AS term,
    COUNT(data) AS term_cnt;
```

4) Than group your data again by some identifier, and MAX
https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.14.0/func.html#max
Or order it to get the top x